# How to capture the time of execution on a Spring Batch tasklet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
public class FpTxnGenerateVoucherHeader
        implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeStep( StepExecution stepExecution) {
        // do nothing

        long startTime = (Long)request.getAttribute("startTime");
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executeTime = endTime - startTime;

        log.info("{}", executeTime);

    }
```

Any help on how I could get the `request.getAttribute("startTime");` work on this method? I get a red text on `request`.

Comment: Why on earth would a Spring Batch tasklet depend on the web? That shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @M.Deinum It was suggested that to capture the time taken for the execution. And he gave that code as a sample.. Is there anyway to implement it?

Comment: Your batch jobs shouldn't depend on the http request, that is a bad idea. The batch processing already logs the start and end time of the jobs, steps, why reinvent the wheel?